# Basic issue with AngularJS directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following **html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <cmp>
        <enhanced-textarea ng-model="name"></enhanced-textarea>
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <notice></notice>
    </cmp>
</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect there is an issue with my **app.js**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

Here is **controllers.js**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'test';
  }]);
```

And finally **directives.js**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('cmp', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'cmpCtrl',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                name: '='
            },
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
    .controller('cmpCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs' , function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$parent.$watch('name', function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $scope.$parent.updatedSize = newVal.length;
                console.log(newVal.length);
            }
        }, true);
    }])
    .directive('enhancedTextarea', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: '<textarea ng-transclude></textarea>'
        };
    })
    .directive('notice', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^cmp',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                updatedSize: '='
            },
            template: '<div>{{size}}</div>',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, cmpCtrl) {
                console.log(cmpCtrl);
                $scope.$parent.$watch('updatedSize', function (newVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        $scope.size = newVal;
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        };
    });
```

My code is bloated I know, but I am in the process of pruning it down. Bear with me.

**I don't understand why the `size` model attribute inside the `notice` element is not updated...**

Full app is located on github [here](https://github.com/balteo/angularjs-directives/tree/master/app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is scope inheritance, your `enhancedTextarea` directive' scope inherits the `name` property from your controller because it's **undefined**. But as soon as you change the textarea value, it's property is **created** and what you change after that changes this directive's scope property.

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbRUrNN9NshQTlCql3Ev?p=preview).

When you inspect the console **without** changing the textarea, you won't see the `name` property of the scope. When you type something, you see the property is created which will **override** the parent's scope `name` property.

When you change the code like this, it works:

```
<enhanced-textarea ng-model="name"></enhanced-textarea>
<cmp>
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <notice></notice>
</cmp>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3s63ICBzlXyYK75Z2qS?p=preview)

In order to create loosely coupled code, I recommend you not to rely on `$scope.$parent` inside you directives. You should try directive bindings to bind with parent properties.